# left join fetch in sql

Tags: sql, jpa, join, fetch

I got 2 Tables "A" and "B". I want to read data from those tables. First with JPA. If i do the following:

```
select a as a, b as b
from "A" a, "B" b
where ...;
```

i get an lazily initialize error message.

This is why i added the statement

```
left join fetch a."c" c
```

which solved the problem. Now i need the same in SQL statement. What can i use for left join fetch?

If I try

```
select a as a, b as b
from "A" a, "B" b
left join fetch a."c" c
where ...;
```

i get ERROR: Table "Fetch" not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you putting quotes around attributes in JPQL?  JPQL is entity based, not table based.  Try just "Select a, b from A a, B b where ..".  Use the entity name and the attributes mapped within the entity to form your query.

If you are getting a lazy init error, it means you have relationships between entities left unfetched.  Fetching them allows the entity to be serialized, and the relationship used at the other end when deserialized.  But fetch is a JPA only concept - why are you trying to create a JPQL query in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be mixing `FROM a, b` with `LEFT JOIN`. You either use `FROM a,b` with `WHERE` clauses to join entities/tables or you must add the `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToMany` as a property of the entity so you can properly use `LEFT JOIN` if there is a relationship between a, b, or c. To avoid the LazyInitialization you must get the result list of entities from the query and then call the getter of the field name you want to lazy load while you are in a transaction so that Hibernate knows to lazy load it. For example: `a.getC();` Otherwise you can use `SELECT c FROM a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.c c`